# converting class to hooks getting Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, here I have two same codes, one is with classes that work, and another is converted from that same class into hooks.
in hooks version, my 'then' is giving an error

> Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) =>
> Promise'.ts(2339)

have I made some mistake with conversion? 
why it is not giving the same error in class while both are the same?

also `console.log("Fetched model", realGraph.model);` should give an object but it is giving `undefined`(in-class version it works), but if I put this console outside of loadGraph function then it gives an object, why it's not giving an object inside loadGraph function?

any ideas and suggestions?

class:

```
import { getGraph, getFloorplan, changeActiveCamera } from '../redux/actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentSite: state.selection.currentSite,
    currentCamera: state.selection.currentCamera,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getGraph: (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site)),
    getFloorplan: (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site)),
    changeActiveCamera: (site, id) => dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id)),
  };
}

loadGraph() {
  if (this.props.currentSite) {
    this.props.getFloorplan(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
      console.log('Fetched floorplan');

      this.props.getGraph(this.props.currentSite.identif).then(() => {
        console.log('Fetched model', this.props.realGraph.model);

        // new camera-related node & link status
        if (this.props.currentCamera) {
          this.props.changeActiveCamera(
            this.props.currentSite.identif,
            this.props.currentCamera.identif
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

converted from class to hooks:

Hooks:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const realGraph = useSelector((state) => state.graphArticles.graph);

const currentSite = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentSite);
const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => state.selection.currentCamera);
const dispatchGetFloorplan = (site) => dispatch(getFloorplan(site));
const dispatchGetGraph = (site) => dispatch(getGraph(site));
const dispatchChangeActiveCamera = (site, id) =>
  dispatch(changeActiveCamera(site, id));

const loadGraph = () => {
  if (currentSite) {
    dispatchGetFloorplan(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
      console.log('Fetched floorplan');

      dispatchGetGraph(currentSite.identif).then(() => {
        console.log('Fetched model', realGraph.model);

        // new camera-related node & link status
        if (currentCamera) {
          dispatchChangeActiveCamera(
            currentSite.identif,
            currentCamera.identif
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

my action related to those:

```
export function getGraph(site) {
  return getData(`api/graph/${site}`, GET_GRAPHS);
}

export function getFloorplan(site) {
  return getImage(`api/graph/${site}/floorplan`, GET_FLOORPLAN);
}
```

Comment: would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, there are several things I would change in the code you provided.

First, don't use any wrapper factories over your dispatch functions. Use dispatch(action()) directly where you need it component. You aren't gaining anything by creating wrapper functions.

Second, it would be advisable to use some sort of middleware, like [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), to handle async Redux actions (like fetching something from the API).

The actions you provided are just "dumb" functions, which are not returning promises so you can't expect it to be "then"-able in your target component.

I also advise [the async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax since it is much more readable.

Third, you need to leverage the Hooks reactive API with the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

---

So first try to define **getFloorPlan** and **getGraph** as async actions using the redux-thunk syntax.

```
export const getGraphAsync = (site) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = await getData(`api/graph/${site}`, GET_GRAPHS);
    dispatch(saveGraphData(data))  // save data into Redux store with a normal, synchronous action (plain object)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

export const getFloorplanAsync = (site) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const data = await getImage(`api/graph/${site}/floorplan`, GET_FLOORPLAN);
    dispatch(saveImageData(data))  // save data into Redux store with a normal, synchronous action (plain object)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

I am making an assumption that you correctly configured your store.js to use the thunk middleware.

And then refactor the rest of the component (following some best practices):

```
const someHookComponent = () => {

  // ...

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const currentSite = useSelector((state) => 
    state.selection.currentSite);
  const currentCamera = useSelector((state) => 
    state.selection.currentCamera);

  const loadGraph = async () => {
    if (currentSite) {
      await dispatch(getFloorPlanAsync(currentSite.identif));
      console.log('Fetched floorplan');

      await dispatch(getGraphAsync(currentSite.identif));
      console.log('Fetched model', realGraph.model); /* where is 
      realGraph coming from? */

      /* Why is it important that these 2 dispatches follow one 
         another when there is no data being passed from one to the 
         other, or being used later in the component... */
      });
     });
   }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   // new camera-related node & link status
    if (currentCamera) {
      dispatch(changeActiveCamera(
        currentSite.identif,
        currentCamera.identif
      ));
    }
  }, [currentSite?.identif, currentCamera?.identif]) /* null chaining is optional here */

  // ...

}
```

I am guessing that `loadGraph` gets called by some onClick event somewhere down the line like this:

```
onClick={loadGraph}
```

If it is called inside useEffect, define the deps (variables used inside loadGraph):

```
useDeepCompareEffect(() => { 
  // ... some logic

  loadGraph() 
}, [currentSite, realGraph])
```

If you put your currentSite and currentCamera objects directly into the useEffect list of deps then you need to do a deep comparison "by hand".

In that case it's best to create a custom hook like [useDeepCompareEffect](https://github.com/sandiiarov/use-deep-compare) which will do the heavy lifting of running deep comparisons of reference types under the hood (with the help of some library like lodash for example).

If you want to use or console.log the latest value of **realGraph** (reference type), you need to use the useEffect hook with a deep comparison again (or just extract the target primitive directly into the deps list and use vanilla useEffect) :

```
  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    if (realGraph) {
       console.log('Fetched model', realGraph.model);
    }
  }, [realGraph]) // reference type

  // or
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (realGraph) {
       console.log('Fetched model', realGraph.model);
    }
  }, [realGraph.someProperty]) // primitive
```

Comment: Ok. The first step would then be to use redux-thunk for your async actions. It is considered to be among the best practices anyway. After you refactor you can see if the problem persists.

Comment: Now you need to define an async action in thunk syntax (look at the docs). Normal actions should be plain objects.

Comment: still getting Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other

Comment: I added the thunk actions in my original answer.

Comment: you have mistake here : export function getGraphAsync = (site) => async (dispatch) => {, it says ''(' expected.ts(1005)
'

Comment: did you mean 'export const getGraphAsync = (site) => async (dispatch) => {
'

Comment: Yes, exactly. const instead of function. It was a typo.. I fixed it.

Comment: ReferenceError: saveImageData is not defined, and also on await it says 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

Comment: You need to define **saveImageData** (if you need something like that.) It is just an example of how to use a synchronous action inside a thunk. I will stop commenting at this point because I have given you enough clues and help to continue by yourself.

Comment: could you answer my question in question 'why class version works ?' ? i dont need to add thunk or anything with that class code, why ?